# Multiple inner redirect

Tags: bash, github-actions

I am looking a a [Github workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-6) and trying to figure out what the following redirect is doing:

```
echo 'JSON_RESPONSE<<EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
curl https://httpbin.org/json >> $GITHUB_ENV
echo 'EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

The "heredoc" is to the "eof" right, but what is these inner redirect doing?

Comment: There's no pipe there.

Comment: `>>` has nothing to do with a here-doc; it's the output redirection operator for *appending* to an existing file rather than truncating it first.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "inner redirect", it's just GitHub Actions' syntax for setting complex environment variables using a syntax similar to Bash heredocs.

It's documented [exactly above your link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings) and describes the following syntax:

```
{name}<<{delimiter}
{value}
{delimiter}
```

The file produced by the example has the following content:

```
JSON_RESPONSE<<EOF
data downloaded with curl
EOF
```

So `{name}` will be `JSON_RESPONSE` and `{value}` will be `data downloaded with curl`, which will then be parsed by GitHub Actions runner for setting the environment variable for subsequent steps.

Answer (score -1):

It's putting a command with a here-doc in the file named in the variable `GITHUB_ENV`. So after these statements, that file will contain

```
JSON_RESPONSE<<EOF
data downloaded with curl
EOF
```

This will then execute the `JSON_RESPONSE` command with that JSON file as its standard input.